# Os likes / shares do Facebook deixaram de aparecer em minhas páginas

Tags: javascript, json

Até algum tempo atrás utilizava esta URL para recuperar dados em JSON do Facebook e exibir em minhas páginas através do JavaScript: https://graph.facebook.com/?id=URL.
No entanto, os likes ou shares deixaram de ser exibidos e isso em todos os meus sites. Já pesquisei e sei que o Facebook atualizou sua Open Graph, porém não consegui uma maneira simples de resolver este problema. 
Alguém teria alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, depois de muito pesquisar, encontrei a resposta. Aparentemente, o Facebook não está mais aceitando chamadas via GET sem o uso de um token de acesso. Acabei usando a mesma URL da pergunta acima porém, acrescentando alguns parâmetros. Então, ficou assim:

```url
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/?id=URL_DA_PAGINA&fields=engagement&access_token=TOKEN_DE_ACESSO_DO_APLICATIVO
```

Utilizei o token de acesso de um aplicativo que eu já tinha criado no Facebook Developers e refiz a URL total. O JSON gerado pelo Facebook, agora, é algo como esse abaixo:

```
{
   "engagement": {
      "reaction_count": 70,
      "comment_count": 52,
      "share_count": 61,
      "comment_plugin_count": 0
   },
   "id": "http://www.endereco-da-pagina-pesquisada"
}
```

Para capturar os dados, então, será necessária uma chamada como essa dentro do JavaScript:

```
var MeusAcessos = parseInt(data.engagement.share_count);
```

Isso resolveu meu problema. Caso alguém leia esta resposta e precise de mais alguma informação, poste sua dúvida.